# Unable to upload image file using FTP

Tags: php, ftp

As the first step FTP connection and login both work. Then I tried

```
$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftpcon, ".");
var_dump($file_list);
```

and able to see `test` folder in the results.

in addition, I checked for directory existence using `ftp_chdir` and it seems okay,

```
ftp_chdir($ftpcon, "test")
```

finally I am trying to upload an image (png) using,

```
$remote_dir = 'test/';
$src_file = $_FILES['srcfile']['name'];
$remote_file_path = $remote_dir . $src_file;

if (ftp_put($ftpcon, $remote_file_path, $src_file, FTP_BINARY))
    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
else
    echo 'Error uploading file!';
```

but getting a warning and `Error uploading file!` message,

```
ftp_put(image.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Guido Faecke and @MartinPrikryl for pointing me out, `name` should be used for the remote path, and `tmp_name` should be used for the file path.

The correction would be,

```
$remote_dir = 'test/';
$src_name = $_FILES['srcfile']['name'];
$remote_file_path = $remote_dir . $src_name;

$temp_file_path = $_FILES['srcfile']['tmp_name'];

if (ftp_put($ftpcon, $remote_file_path, $temp_file_path, FTP_BINARY))
    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
else
    echo 'Error uploading file!';
```